# Argument list too long with just 5000 files

Tags: bash, cp

I have a folder with **5000** files that I want to copy somewhere else.

When I do `cp ../folder* .`, I get the following error:

```
-bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long
```

However, `getconf ARG_MAX` returns `262144`.

```
$ echo ../folder* |wc
1 5015 69144
```

Is this normal? I had been able to copy all those files before.

Comment: ARG_MAX is a character limit, not an parameter count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a program to iterate over the arguments:

e.g. `find .. -type d -iname '*/folder*' -exec cp -a {} . \;`

of manually iterate with a loop, such as:

`for myDir in ../folder* ; do cp -a "$myDir" . ; done`

There are many other ways, but one of the above should do the trick for you.
(The for-loop example might be slower)

Comment: wouldn't `find ... -exec cp ... +` run into the very same problem of having too many arguments as `find` will batch the output or is there a limit for batching size with `+`?

Comment: @Fiximan : I would consider it a bug in  "find", if it offered "+" to batch arguments, without checking local system argument count limits. And since "find" is ancient software, they should have thought about, and fixed any bugs in this functionality decades ago.